# toString in Fortran

Tags: fortran, tostring

In Java there is a nifty function that any class descending from `Object` has:

```
public String toString()
```

the function in it self is not very magical, but the way that the Java interpreter uses it makes it very, well, useful.  And, of course, this in not something that is of live-or-die importance, but a very nice-to-have, making life easier for somewhat lazy coders.  As far as I can tell anything similar doesn't exist in Fortran (or in many other languages).

*Am I wrong?  Does something like this exist?  Or, is there something similar hidden in Fortran lore?*

For those who are not familiar with Java:  Simply (but slightly inaccurate) said, if an object variable is used (without referring to any of its members) in any place that a String is expected, the Java interpreter looks up the `toString()` method for the variable's class, defaulting up through the hierarchy (all the way to `Object`).  Thus, every object has some `toString()` available.

Implementing a `toString()` function into a class (or type) in Fortran is not much hazzle.  Well, that kinda depends on the complexity of the type, and on what the user wants the function to return.

It would be far more convenient to write:

```
    write(*,*) somevariable
```

instead of

```
    write(*,*) somevariable%toString()
```

similar for assignments of course

```
    character (len = *) :: str
    str = somevariable
```

instead of

```
    str = somevariable%toString()
```

This is, of course, related to type casting.  Implicit type casting, if I am not mistaken.

I am **not** looking to start a long discussion on this, as I have little more to contribute than what I have already written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortran doesn't have a strong concept of "if object of type Y is given where one of type X is expected, convert it to one of type X". This covers different types of numeric objects (Y double precision, X real, say) as much as derived types and strings.

You'll see this in things like argument mismatches in procedure references and so on.

We do have type conversion in some cases, like in `x+y` where those two objects are of different types.

So, a reference like `somevariable` is always<sup>1</sup> a reference to that object, rather than any one (or more) of its components or type-bound procedures/binding names.

In something like

```
call dosomething(somevariable)
```

where `dosomething` expects a character but `somevariable` is not a character, there can never be an implicit conversion carried out for you.

However, in the two cases you are interested in, there are means to say instead that `somevariable` as a derived type is expected, but that something else happens instead of immediately processing that type.

1. For data transfer, defined input/output can be used
2. For assignment to a character, defined assignment can be used

For example (see other questions and answers for precise explanations), we can define a type `t` with a generic `write(formatted)` and an interface for `assignment(=)` which has a character left-hand side and `type(t)` right-hand side:

```
module mod
  type t
     integer :: i=0
   contains
     procedure :: write
     generic :: write(formatted) => write
  end type t

  interface assignment(=)
     module procedure assign
  end interface assignment(=)
  
contains

  subroutine write(dtv, unit, iotype, v_list, iostat, iomsg)
    class(t), intent(in) :: dtv
    integer, intent(in) :: unit
    character(*), intent(in) :: iotype
    integer, intent(in) :: v_list(:)
    integer, intent(out) :: iostat
    character(*), intent(inout) :: iomsg
  
    write (unit, "(A)", iostat=iostat, iomsg=iomsg) "Object says hello"
  end subroutine write

  subroutine assign(lhs, rhs)
    character(:), allocatable, intent(out) :: lhs
    class(t), intent(in) :: rhs

    lhs = "From assignment"
  end subroutine assign

end module mod
```

The defined output procedure can be called with the `dt` edit descriptor (or using list-directed output), and the defined assignment as usual:

```
  use mod, only : t, assignment(=)
  character(:), allocatable :: str

  print '(dt)', t()

  str = t()
  print '(A)', str
end
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The reference to a derived type object can be expanded to its *component order* in intrinsic data transfer of the object when those components are all accessible.

Answer (score 2):

In Fortran, conversion of variables from internal format to strings is done with "Internal WRITE". For example:

```
character(100) :: str
write (str,*) somevariable
```

In the case of a derived type variable, if the components are all intrinsic types (or other derived types with intrinsic types), the components will be output in order. If you have any pointer or allocatable components, or if you have special requirements on formatting, you would declare a "user-defined derived type I/O procedure" to do that, which would then be automatically called as needed during I/O operations.

You may have noticed that above I declared the variable `str` to have a specific length, as today you need to do that. Fortran 2023, to be published later this year, allows you to declare `str` as a deferred-length allocatable variable instead, and the internal write will (re)allocate it to the necessary length. Of course, you'll need to wait for compilers to implement that feature.